# What is "split chicken"?

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, slaughter-shochet-shecht

Recently I have noticed in Lubavitch butchers they sell "split chickens" which i was told is a term that is halachic and has to do with the salting process.

Can someone enlighten me on what this is?

Comment: Has to do with if/how they access and/or salt the inside of the cavity (pretty sure we had this question already somewhere...)

Comment: I don't believe it is a lubavitche chumrah. They split the chicken in order to properly salt inside. Though this might lead to complications of salting between the skin and flesh which separates when splitting the chicken. I believe it used to be a chumrah but nowadays with modern cleaning processes it doesn't need to be split

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Rabbi Yosef Yeshaya Braun](https://asktherav.com/23636-is-split-chicken-a-hidur/#more-21448) the key reasons for splitting the chickens are:

1. to make sure that the salt goes all the way in, and
2. to make sure that the lungs, heart spleen and kidneys are not there anymore.

He characterizes it as a hiddur (a beautification of the law).

[R. Gedalya Oberlander here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hHfaLHXCFdM&t=483s) characterizes it as a humra (stringency) and suggests that the practice possibly introduces some halakhic problems, and that unless one already has this humra, it ought not be taken on. He also states that though many Lubavitcher shohetim (slaughterers) offer this, he is not certain that it ought be characterized as a Lubavitcher minhag (custom) because there are no Lubavitcher sources that explicitly endorse/prescribe it.

I have not seen this practice outside of Chabad-Lubavitch. Perhaps someone else can chime in with how extant this practice is.